# target correct image for modal in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

My template

```
<div>
<ul>
{% for image in obj.images_set.all %} 
  <li class="col-lg-4 text-center">
     <a data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal{{forloop.counter0}}"> 
     <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt=""/></a>
  </li>

{% endfor %}

</ul>
</div>


{% for image in obj.images_set.all %}
<div id="myModal{{forloop.counter0}}" class="modal fade" 
role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog" style="text-align:center;">
   <div class="modal-content" style="display:inline-block;">
       <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt=""/>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Im having a list of tasks. Im looping over the tasks and an obj represents one task.Each task has multiple images(1,2 or 3).The tasks are listed and the images are displaying correctly.Im trying to show a modal popup when clicking on an image inside a task. Im specifying the target with an id using for loop counter.The problem is that im not able to target the correct image as im having a list of images for each task...SO the for loop goes like 0,1,2 for images in first task and then 0,1,2 also for second task and im not able to assign a unique id for the data-target.How do i overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
<ul>
{% for image in obj.images_set.all %} 
  <li class="col-lg-4 text-center">
   <a data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal{{image.pk}} 
{{forloop.counter0}}"> 
  <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt=""/></a>
  </li>

{% endfor %}

</ul>
</div>


{% for image in obj.images_set.all %}
<div id="myModal{{ image.pk }}{{forloop.counter0}}" class="modal fade" 
 role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="text-align:center;">
 <div class="modal-content" style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt=""/>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Resolved the issue.Just added image.pk to the id nad was able to make id unique